# How to update each value inside Dictionary assigned to object in Select statement of LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

I am absolutely new to LINQ queries and trying to update each dictionary value below using COUNT Function with where clause.

These are the hardcoded values of Dictionary
I want to update above dictionary values inside Select Statement of Linq query

```
SummaryData SD = new SummaryData();
SD.serviceQuantityPair.Add("A",0); // serviceQuantityPair is of Type Dictionary<string,int>
SD.serviceQuantityPair.Add("B",0);
SD.serviceQuantityPair.Add("C",0);
SD.serviceQuantityPair.Add("D",0);
SD.serviceQuantityPair.Add("E",0);
SD.serviceQuantityPair.Add("F",0);


List<SummaryData> sumdata = new List<SummaryData>();

try
{
    groupByDate = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    sumdata = await _dbContext.CovidServiceRequests.AsNoTracking()
                            .Where(wh => wh.CreatedTimestamp >= dFromDate && wh.CreatedTimestamp <= dToDate)
                            .GroupBy(gb => gb.CreatedTimestamp!.Value.Date)
                            .Select(s => new SummaryData()
                            {
                                requestDate = s.Key.ToString(groupByDate),
                                serviceQuantityPair = SD.serviceQuantityPair, // I am trying to update each value in this serviceQuantityPair with Count of each serviceType
                                qty = s.Count(wh => wh.RequestedCode == "A")
                            });
}
catch(Exception ex){}
```

The key value pair of Dictionary are dynamic. So I want once the select statement find any matching records, it counts the no. of rows based on Dictionary Key == Column Value and updated the value in Dictionary

Comment: You are querying a database and changing the `SummaryData.serviceQuantityPair` dictionary based on the results of the query. You are not updating the database. Is all that correct?

Comment: "I am trying to update each value in this serviceQuantityPair with Count of each serviceType" I haven't got a clue what you mean. In your examples you didn't mention ServiceType. Is that a property of ServiceQuantityPair? Does every ServiceQuantityPair have zero or more ServiceTypes? And if you've counted the number of ServiceTypes, what is the Dictionary key? Please update the question with proper definitions of ServiceQuantityPair, and an exact description of your requirements.

Comment: @JonathanDodds Yes. I am not updating the database. I just need to update "value" part of each item in Dictionary based on Count of records fetched matching column value with "Key".

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse Please refer my above comment for reference. Thanks.

Comment: LINQ is for querying, not for updating existing objects. If you need to update the `Dictionary` entries, use LINQ to get the counts, and use `foreach` to update the `Dictionary` entries.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have some CovidService obiect colection, and need group by CreatedTimestamp.Date and get count of each RequestedCode for each date as SummaryData

```
    const string groupByDate = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    IEnumerable<SummaryData> GetSummaryDataItems(ICollection<CovidService> covidService)
        => covidService.GroupBy(gb => gb.CreatedTimestamp.Date,
            (groupDate, groupItems) => new { Date = groupDate, Dict = groupItems.GroupBy(subGroup => subGroup.RequestedCode).ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Count()) }
            ).Select(i => new SummaryData {
                requestDate = i.Date.ToString(groupByDate),
                serviceQuantityPair = i.Dict
            });
```